# Firebase push notification: this.router.navigate doesn't do anything when the app was in background (not stopped, just closed)

Tags: firebase, push-notification, nativescript, angular-router

I am making an app with nativescript and firebase. Recently i found a bug and after passing many hours on google to find a solution, I'm quite desperate.

I use push notifications and in the firebase `onMessageReceivedCallback` function, I navigate to one or another page (with `this.router.navigate` and `ngZone.run()` cause i am out the angular zone in here).
When the app is close or in foreground, I don't have any problems the `router.navigate` is working. But when the app is in background (not stopped, just closed), I don't have any errors but nothing happens, I'm still on the same page.

Somebody has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think UI updates could be done in background, at least on iOS. Wait for resume event and perform pending navigation.

Comment: i am not navigating when the app is in background. I received the push notification when the app is in background. I clicked on it, the app opened and i want to navigate to my specific page once it completely loaded. But nothing happens, i am just on the main page, and i don't have any errors..

Comment: `onMessageReceivedCallback` could be little too early, did you try adding a timeout of may be 1000ms see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Yes i tried. And after add console.loggs, event `activityResumed` is called before `onMessageReceivedCallback`